# Proof by induction: $x^{n+1} < x^n < 1$ for $0 < x < 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on this induction proof.

> If $0<x<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $x^{n+1} < x^n < 1$. If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $m > n$, then $x^m < x^n$

**My attempt so far:**

Base case $P(1)$: true

Assume $P(k)$: $x^{k+1} < x^k < 1$

Show, $P(k+1) = x^{k+1}+ x^{k+1} < x^k + x^{k+1}< 1 + x^{k+1}$

Now, $P(k+1) = P(k) + x^{k+1}$

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You are confusing several things. The title does not match the problem you are stating, for a start. Moreover, $x^{k+2}=x^{k+1}\times x$...

Comment: For $n=1$ we have $x^{1/n} = x = x^{n}$.

Comment: Firstly, conventionally $P(k)$ is a statement, not a number, so you cannot add $x^{k+1}$ to $P(k)$. Second, to prove $P(k+1)$, you have to look at $x^{k+2}$ but not $x^{k+1} + x^{k+1}$

Comment: Finally got right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(k)$ says: $x^{k+1} < x^k < 1$, and you have assumed that $0<x<1$. Take the inequalities that make up $P(k)$, and multiply all sides by $x$. Since $x$ is positive, the inequalities are unchanged, and we get
$$
x^{k+2} < x^{k+1} < x
$$
but we know that $x < 1$, so we can add that to the end:
$$
x^{k+2} < x^{k+1} < x < 1
$$
and now we can jsut strip away the second-to-last term to get
$$
x^{k+2} < x^{k+1} < 1
$$
which is $P(k+1)$.